# How to draw a line with constant width everywhere with respect to the screen In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the title suggests, I would like to render a line in Unity that has constant width on the screen doesn't matter how far the camera is.

A typical example will be something like the orbit line in the game KSP, which is also made with Unity.
[Orbit Lines in KSP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eow34.png)

The line is fixed width and clearly visible from any distance and any angle.

Using LineRenderer and set the width is not the solution because of perspective as the line on the far end will be too thin. (If this is achieve through LineRenderer then the segment on the far side will be much thicker, the line is not the same width everywhere)

Can someone suggests possible ways to achieve that? Any code example or even shader?

Comment: Could probably use the [`GL`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html) API

Answer (score 0):

Take your world space points and transform it using Camera.WorldToScreenPoint or Camera.WorldToScreenPoint to get a 'flat' representation of your curve.

Than, you can still use LineRenderer, or you can use  UILineRenderer from https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/wiki/Controls/UILineRenderer

Comment: I don't think the question was regarding the positions but rather the thickness of the line ;) as OP states the challenge is to have a circular line in world space but in a perspective camera the line should have the same pixel width regardless the perspective

Comment: you may be right